# The colimit is contractible.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let $A_0\xrightarrow{f_0} A_1\xrightarrow{f_1} A_2\xrightarrow{f_2}\cdots$ be a system of cofibrations in which all the $A_i$ are contractible.
How do I prove that $colim_iA_i$ is also contractible?

I so far have this.

We know the diagram
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
A_n&\ra{f_n}&A_{n+1}\\
\da{i_0}&&\da{}\\
A_{n}\times I&\ra{}&Cylf_n
\end{array}
$$
exists for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $Cylf_n$ is the mapping cylinder of $f_n$.
We also know the diagram 
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
A_n&\ra{f_n}&A_{n+1}\\
\da{i_0}&&\da{i_0}\\
A_{n}\times I&\ra{f_n\times id_I}&A_{n+1}\times I
\end{array}
$$
exists.
Since $Cylf_n$ is a pushout, there exists a unique map $\alpha_n:Cylf_n\to A_{n+1}\times I$ that makes the appropriate diagram commute.  Since $f_n$ is a cofibration, there exists a continuous function $\beta_n:A_{n+1}\times I\to Cylf_n$ that is a left inverse for $\alpha_n$ which means that $\beta_n\alpha_n=id_{Cylf_n}$.

Now since each $A_n$ is contractible, there exists continuous functions, $g_n:A_n\to *$ and $h_n:*\to A_n$ such that $g_n\circ h_n\sim id_*$ and $h_n\circ g_n\sim id_{A_n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This means there exists homotopies $H_n:*\times I\to *$ and $\hat H_n:A_n\times I\to A_n$ such that $H_n(*,t)=*, \hat H_n(x,0)=x,$ and $\hat H_n(x,1)=g_n(h_n(x))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I would suggest show that the inclusions of each $A_i$ into the colimit are cofibrations, then extend contractions of each $A_i$ to the colimit and then compose them all with the usual $0,1/2,3/4,7/8,\ldots$ trick. I didn't verify that this works though, but it looks like it should.

Comment: What is the usual 0, 1/2, 3/4, 7/8,... trick?

Comment: The one for composing infinitely many homotopies by running them faster and faster

Comment: OH. Thank you. Now I know what you mean.

Comment: @jgon How do you suppose I run the homotopies together? I got that the inclusions are cofibrations and that they satisfy the homotopy extension property. But there seems no reasonable way to run them together.